# There has been an error processing your request Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, database

> {"0":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory","1":"#1 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() called at [vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:410]\n#2 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() called at ......

What does this error means, it keeps reporting the same again and again. How do i solve this

Comment: make sure is MySQL running? and check the database details are correct in env.php?

Comment: Please restart mysql and apache sever

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i did restart, but after few days it will get same kinda error. There is bunch of similar errors, Some says about theme, some about extensions used etc.

Comment: Hi, @BilalUsean MySQL is running i guess, If i feel my website lags then there in var/report folder is on hot. Keep producing same kinda error with some numbers modified. here are some other different logs `{"0":"Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log.","1":"#1 `,   and `{"0":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away","1":"#1 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() called at....`. At finally it will end up with "There has been an error processing your request" And it will get back to normal i guess. {Also read my below reply} please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to your MySQL server has stopped so you can restart using the below command. Or you can take help of your server team or this issue may be occur due to db corrupt.so please check it also

To restart, start or stop MySQL server from the command line, type the following at the shell prompt…

On Linux start/stop/restart from the command line:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
 /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
 /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Some Linux flavors offer the service command too

```
service mysqld start
 service mysqld stop
 service mysqld restart

or

 service mysql start
 service mysql stop
 service mysql restart
```

On macOS Sierra & OSX to start/stop/restart MySQL post 5.7  from the command line:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

On OS X to start/stop/restart MySQL pre 5.7  from the command line:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
    sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
    sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
```

Please accept it if this solution work, Thanks

Comment: yeah i did this about 2 times, past 3 weeks. it keeps reporting the same logs. Some times the site will go offline by displaying error message "There has been an error processing your request". and it will get back to normal after few mins. Is it something related to ram or any other bottle necking related issue?..Because at this time Ram usage shows 108 (Varies up to 1058) MB free out of 3951.

Comment: please make sure that the database is not corrupt. if it's not then it's related to server.you should take help of them or should try to debug that is your code running some big process or not.